# how can i use script function in ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to use a script function in ejs.

I thought it would be simple, but no matter how I searched, I couldn't find any information.

***test.ejs***

```
<body>
<h1><% sum_ab(1,2) %></h1> // I want 3 to come out here.
<script>
function sum_ab(a,b) {
 var sum = a+b;
 return sum;
}
</script>
<body>
```

***error message : sum_ab is not defined***

I want to know how to use script function in ejs file.

Comment: Mybe you forgot the equals sign ````<%= sum_ab(1,2) %>````

Comment: You can't call this way. You'll need to use JS to update the text.

Comment: Take a look at tags in the docs: https://ejs.co/#docs

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken that you cannot separate area (//this is js code) for write javascript codes. You can use js code within the HTML codes. I prepared an example code following according to your code:

```
            </div>
        <% function sum_ab(a,b) {
            var sum = a+b;
            return sum;
            }%>
        <h1><%= sum_ab(3,6) %></h1>
    </div>
```

Please try this code in the .ejs file. It'll be work.